# Is there a way to access to the database of Google Maps for the public transport?

Tags: database, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, gtfs

I'd like to have access to the numbers and type of public transportation and for each of them, their stops of a certain city. So for instance, I'd like to have :

```
Number    Type    Stops
1         Metro   Stop1.1, Stop1.2, Stop1.3, ...
6         Bus     Stop6.1, Stop6.2, Stop6.3, ...
17        Tram    Stop17.1, Stop17.2, Stop17.3, ...
...       ...     ...
```

Of course, I don't really care about the format, I just want to know how to have access to the data, in order to do not re-enter it manually in my website!

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GTFS Data Exchange](http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/agency/oc-transpo/)

Comment: Great, thanks ! For anyone interested for Brussels' data : http://www.stib.be/data-sharing.html?l=en

Answer (score 2):

GTFS Exchange was retired in 2016. 
It is still useful for legacy gtfs files that are not updated/available anymore. However, you should now refer to the following databases for [static GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/):

1. [Transitland](https://transit.land/)
2. [TransitFeeds](http://transitfeeds.com/)
3. [TransitWiki](https://www.transitwiki.org/TransitWiki/index.php/Publicly-accessible_public_transportation_data)
4. [Google's own compilation: PublicFeeds.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googletransitdatafeed/wikis/PublicFeeds.wiki)

They overlap a lot but not completely, so it's always good to check all of them out. Also know that some smaller transit agencies still don't share their data with these services, so it's worth checking their website.

Finally, Google map uses these same files as their source data to my knowledge. In their [reference page for GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/), they mention the following:

> **Submitting a Transit feed to Google**
>   If you're at a public agency that oversees public transportation for your city, you can use the GTFS specification to provide schedules and geographic information to Google Maps and other Google applications that show transit information.
>
> If you provide a transportation service that is open to the public, and operates with fixed schedules and routes, we welcome your participation; it is simple and free.

For live updates though, I think that google uses [GTFS RealTime](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/#what_is_live_transit_updates_for_google_maps).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way... in a word, no.  This data isn't available through the Maps API (yet).

Comment: Very useful link, but nothing to to with Google Maps' database

Comment: Indeed, at first I thought that it was GMaps who referenced all the datas but apparently, for some legal reasons, the data is private and belongs to the public transportation company. So it must be that company which has decided to give access to its data and the GTFS format has the advantage to be uniformized. So for those reasons, Gmaps is using GTFS!